# How to compile different source files with different options for a single target using CMake?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compilation, cmake

I would like your help since I am a newbie when it comes to CMake. Let's say I have an executable target T that depends on source files A.c, B.cpp and c.cpp. I would like to compile A.c with specific flags and create the object file A.o. For simplicity let's assume B and C will be compiled with g++ with the same set of flags, and corresponding object files should be created as B.o C.o. Then I can link these object files and produce the T with gcc. I know I can do it in a few steps with a regular makefile. Basically, I have trouble compiling A.c with specific flags and the rest of the files with same flags. I don't know how exactly it should be done with CMake?

```
add_executable(T A.c B.cpp C.cpp)
```

I know CMake offers a `target_compile_options()` but I do not how to use it for my case? I guess it can be set for global flags of the target, but not for what I am after!

Comment: What I ended up doing was to create another library target for A.c, but passed in the OBJECT argument as described in [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library) with desired option and flags. And for the actual target, I was able to use `add_executable(T B.cpp C.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>)`. So, B and C will be compiled with the other option, then will be linked with A.o.

Comment: Your comment is the correct answer. I suggest writing it as an answer and accepting it as the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set specific flags for individual source files, you need to work with the source file properties. You use either [`set_property(SOURCE...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) or [`set_source_files_properties()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html) to do that. The source properties you are likely to be interested in are [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) and [`COMPILE_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_FLAGS.html). For example:

```
# set_source_files_properties() always replaces any previous value
set_source_files_properties(A.c PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS MySpecialOption=1
)

# Only set_property() allows appending to existing values
set_property(SOURCE A.c APPEND_STRING PROPERTY
    COMPILE_FLAGS " -Wno-unused"
)
```